# Can I directly send encoded information's in forms that have GET method?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have html form that use GET method, but i want to send information not so obvious. For example to put simple base64 encoding. I need unique URL so every time same information is needed, we need to have same and not so obvious URL.

example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?myname=johnDoe
```

but I need not so obvious:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?bXluYW1lJTNEam9obkRvZQ==
```

This is simple base64 encryption.

Comment: Do you want to encode the whole query string parameters or each parameter by itself?

Comment: *"i want to send information not so obvious"* - You should look into `POST` requests - they act in a similar way except the parameters are sent as headers and are not appended to the URL.

Comment: The browser will automatically URL-encode all the form fields, and PHP will automatically decode it. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: @esqew To be precise, the parameters are sent as the body, not the header.

Comment: First of all, if you are worried about security, base64 doesn't help at all. But if you need to send a base64 encoded string to a server, your second url needs to have a name after the ?. so like index.php?code=bXl3s.... I think you might also need to url encode the base64 string.

Comment: It isn't important, i would like whole string, but each param will be fine solution too.
And I don't want to use POST, cause i need unique URL

Comment: and again... I dont want safe, just unique URL, when I send same information, and I dont want to URL look so obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET and POST data are stored in the superglobals `$_GET` and `$_POST` as associative arrays.  All you really need to do is use the `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` methods.  The only problem is that you can't call those methods on arrays, but you can call it on strings.  That's where `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` come into play.

```
$array   = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2); // substitute $_GET or $_POST here 
$json    = json_encode($array);
$string  = base64_encode($json);

echo $string; // this is the base64-encoded string

$json    = base64_decode($string);
$array   = json_decode($json);

print_r($array); // this is an associative array
```

You can have your form GET or POST to a converter page, which converts the POST or GET array into a base64-encoded string, then redirect using `header()` to the page that needs the special URL.

The receiving page can then reverse the process to get the input form the form.

Answer (score 0):

After encoding the query string, base on what you prepared in your question, you can do this in php side of the `index.php`

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?'.$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$url_array = parse_url($url);
$encodedURL = $url_array['query'];
$decodeURL = base64_decode($encodedURL);
```